# Dependent DropDown Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

i`m creating dynamic dropdown box i have 2 dropdown each of my dropdown have a different data once i selected it it will channge the other data depending on what you select in the first dropdown how to achieve that?

i tried this code but it gaves me a `undentified`

```
.TS
```

this is what iwanted to put in my dropdown box once i click the SERVICEABLE it will populate all the maintenance,upgrage,repairable and once i click the UNSERVICEABLE it will change it to another data and list all unserviceable

````
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "assetID": 9,
    "tranType": "MAINTENANCE",
    "assetConditionType": {
      "id": 9,
      "assetConditionType": "SERVICEABLE"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "assetID": 9,
    "tranType": "UPGRADE",
    "assetConditionType": {
      "id": 9,
      "assetConditionType": "SERVICEABLE"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "assetID": 9,
    "tranType": "REPAIRABLE",
    "assetConditionType": {
      "id": 9,
      "assetConditionType": "SERVICEABLE"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "assetID": 10,
    "tranType": "DISPOSAL",
    "assetConditionType": {
      "id": 10,
      "assetConditionType": "UNSERVICEABLE"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 5,
    "assetID": 10,
    "tranType": "WRITTEN-OFF",
    "assetConditionType": {
      "id": 10,
      "assetConditionType": "UNSERVICEABLE"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 6,
    "assetID": 10,
    "tranType": "RETIRED",
    "assetConditionType": {
      "id": 10,
      "assetConditionType": "UNSERVICEABLE"
    }
  }
]


assetDS: AssetCondtionDTO[];
  assetObj: any;


'selectedType(trigger: MatSelectChange) {
  this.assetObj = trigger.value;

  const selectedItem = this.assetDS.find((x) => x.tranType.assetID == trigger.value);
  if (selectedItem) this.serviceLogArray.get('tranType').patchValue(selectedItem.id);
  console.log(this.assetObj)
}
assetCondition(){
  this.serviceSVC.getAssetCondition(5,10).subscribe((res: AssetCondtionDTO) => {
    this.assetObj = res;
  })
}'



HTML

 <td>
  <mat-select formControlName="assetCondition" style="width:200px;padding:10px"
           (selectionChange)="selectedType($event)">
      <mat-option ngFor="let items of assetObj" [value]="items.id">
          {{items.id}}
      </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</td>
 <td>
<mat-select formControlName="tranType" style="width:200px;padding:10px">
     <mat-option ngFor="let items of assetObj" [value]="items.tranType.assetID">
       {{items.tranType.tranType}}</mat-option></mat-select> </td> ```
````

Comment: Something seems to be missing from your question..

Comment: Maybe you can add an example so we understand better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code portion of your question is unclear and we can't understand written logic but from your description, I provide you an example to filter a fake list base on another select form control:

Template:

```
<form [formGroup]="formGroup">
  <div>
    <mat-select formControlName="assetCondition" style="width:200px;padding:10px"
             (selectionChange)="selectedType($event)">
        <mat-option *ngFor="let items of assetConditionTypes" [value]="items.id">
            {{items.assetConditionType}}
        </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
  </div>
  <div>
    <mat-select formControlName="tranType" style="width:200px;padding:10px">
         <mat-option *ngFor="let items of filteredAssets" [value]="items.assetID">
           {{items.tranType}}
          </mat-option>
         <mat-option *ngIf="filteredAssets.length===0">
           Pleas select type first!
          </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
  </div>
</form>
```

TS:

```
formGroup: FormGroup = new FormGroup({
    assetCondition: new FormControl(''),
    tranType: new FormControl('')
  });

  selectedType(trigger: MatSelectChange) {
    this.filteredAssets = this.myAssets.filter((asset) => asset.assetConditionType.id == +trigger.value);
    console.log(this.filteredAssets);
  }

  assetConditionTypes = [
    {
    "id": 9,
    "assetConditionType": "SERVICEABLE"
    },
    {
      "id": 10,
      "assetConditionType": "UNSERVICEABLE"
    }
  ];

  filteredAssets: any[] = [];

  myAssets = [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "assetID": 9,
      "tranType": "MAINTENANCE",
      "assetConditionType": {
        "id": 9,
        "assetConditionType": "SERVICEABLE"
      }
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "assetID": 9,
      "tranType": "UPGRADE",
      "assetConditionType": {
        "id": 9,
        "assetConditionType": "SERVICEABLE"
      }
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "assetID": 9,
      "tranType": "REPAIRABLE",
      "assetConditionType": {
        "id": 9,
        "assetConditionType": "SERVICEABLE"
      }
    },
    {
      "id": 4,
      "assetID": 10,
      "tranType": "DISPOSAL",
      "assetConditionType": {
        "id": 10,
        "assetConditionType": "UNSERVICEABLE"
      }
    },
    {
      "id": 5,
      "assetID": 10,
      "tranType": "WRITTEN-OFF",
      "assetConditionType": {
        "id": 10,
        "assetConditionType": "UNSERVICEABLE"
      }
    },
    {
      "id": 6,
      "assetID": 10,
      "tranType": "RETIRED",
      "assetConditionType": {
        "id": 10,
        "assetConditionType": "UNSERVICEABLE"
      }
    }
  ];
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need transform your data "grouping" in an object like

```
  [
    {
      "id": 9,
      "assetConditionType": "SERVICEABLE",
      "items": [
        {
          "id": 1,
          "assetID": 9,
          "tranType": "MAINTENANCE"
          "assetConditionType": {
            "id": 9,
            "assetConditionType": "SERVICEABLE"
          }
        },
        ...
      ]
    }
    ...
  ]
```

For this we use [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce). Reduce it's no so complex looks like. Imagine you has an array data

```
const dataTransformed=data.reduce((a,b)=>{
   return function(a,b)
},initial)
```

If like a loop

```
   let a=initial
   for (let i=0;i<data.length;i++)
   {
     b=data[i];
     a=function(a,b)
   }
   const dataTransformed=a
```

So you can use reduce and rxjs map operator in the way

```
getData(){
   return this.httpClient.get(..your url...).pipe(
      map((data: any[]) => {
        const groupData=data.reduce((a: any, b: any) => {
          const id = b.assetConditionType.id;
          const element = a.find((x: any) => x.id == id);
          
          if (element) element.items.push(b);
          else
          {
          a.push({
              id: id,
              assetConditionType: b.assetConditionType.assetConditionType,
              items: [b],
            });
          }
          return a;
        }, []);
        return groupData
      })
    );
  }
```

One time you has your data grouped, as you has a few data you can use some like

```
<mat-form-field appearance="fill">
  <mat-label>Asset</mat-label>
  <mat-select [(ngModel)]="value" (selectionChange)="value2=null">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let item of obs|async" [value]="item">
      {{item.assetConditionType}}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
<mat-form-field appearance="fill">
  <mat-label>Transation</mat-label>
  <mat-select [(ngModel)]="value2">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let item of value?.items" [value]="item">
      {{item.tranType}}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

See that "value" has the whole object grouped, so we can use value.items to give value to the options of the second dropdown

I use [(ngModel)] you can use ReactiveForms. If only are interesting in the "items" only use a FormControl to get the item.

Some like

```
form=new FormGroup({
   asset:new FormControl()
})

<form [formGroup]="form">
    <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
      ...
      <mat-select [(ngModel)]="value" (selectionChange)="value2=null">
                   [ngModelOptions]="{standalone:true}"
        <mat-option *ngFor="let item of obs|async" [value]="item">
          {{item.assetConditionType}}
        </mat-option>
      </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>
    <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
      ...
      <mat-select formControlName="asset">
        <mat-option *ngFor="let item of value?.items" [value]="item">
          {{item.tranType}}
        </mat-option>
      </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>
</form>
```

See that the "value" is not belong to the form (it's only a auxiliar variable). As not belong to the form you use `[(ngModel)]` and `[ngModelOptions]="{standalone:true}"`

NOTE: If you only want the "id" use in the second dropdown `[value]="item.id"`

a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xvs5ud?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdata.service.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fselect-overview-example.html)

**Update** If we want the "two values", the "id" and the "assetID" we can take three aproach

1. Store in the formControl an object with this two values

   ```
     form=new FormGroup({
       control:new FormControl()
     })

   <form [formGroup]="form">
     <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
       <mat-label>Asset</mat-label>
       <mat-select
         [(ngModel)]="value"
         [ngModelOptions]="{standalone:true}"
         (selectionChange)="form.get('control')?.setValue(null)"
       >
         <mat-option *ngFor="let item of obs|async" [value]="item">
           {{item.assetConditionType}}
         </mat-option>
       </mat-select>
     </mat-form-field>
     <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
       <mat-label>Transation</mat-label>
       <mat-select formControlName="control">
         <mat-option
           *ngFor="let item of value?.items"
           [value]="{id:item.id,assetID:item.assetID}"
         >
           {{item.tranType}}
         </mat-option>
       </mat-select>
     </mat-form-field>
   </form>
   ```
2. Use the event (changeEnd) to give value to the formControl

   ```
   form2=new FormGroup({
       assetID:new FormControl<number|null>(null),
       id:new FormControl<number|null>(null),
     })
   <form [formGroup]="form2">
     <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
       <mat-label>Asset</mat-label>
       <mat-select
         [(ngModel)]="value"
         [ngModelOptions]="{standalone:true}"
         (selectionChange)="form2.get('assetID')?.setValue(value.id);form2.get('id')?.setValue(null)"
       >
         <mat-option *ngFor="let item of obs|async" [value]="item">
           {{item.assetConditionType}}
         </mat-option>
       </mat-select>
     </mat-form-field>
     <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
       <mat-label>Transation</mat-label>
       <mat-select formControlName="id">
         <mat-option
           *ngFor="let item of value?.items"
           [value]="item.id"
         >
           {{item.tranType}}
         </mat-option>
       </mat-select>
     </mat-form-field>
   </form>
   ```
3. Or use two auxiliar variables: one with all the options and another one with the selected option

   ```
     options: any[] = [];
     selectedOptions: any[];

     form3=new FormGroup({
       assetID:new FormControl<number|null>(null),
       id:new FormControl<number|null>(null),
     })
     ngOnInit() {
       this.dataService.getData().subscribe((res: any[]) => {
         this.options = res;
       });
     }

     getOptions(value: any) {
       this.selectedOptions = this.options.find((x) => x.id == value).items;
     }

   <form [formGroup]="form3">
     <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
       <mat-label>Asset</mat-label>
       <mat-select
         formControlName="assetID"
         (selectionChange)="getOptions($event.value)"
       >
         <mat-option *ngFor="let item of options" [value]="item.id">
           {{item.assetConditionType}}
         </mat-option>
       </mat-select>
     </mat-form-field>
     <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
       <mat-label>Transation</mat-label>
       <mat-select formControlName="id">
         <mat-option
           *ngFor="let item of selectedOptions"
           [value]="item.id"
         >
           {{item.tranType}}
         </mat-option>
       </mat-select>
     </mat-form-field>
   </form>
   ```

see a [new stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xvs5ud-ujo3ex?file=src%2Fapp%2Fselect-overview-example.ts)

Comment: what if i want it to patch it to my form array

Comment: In this case you need use an array for the ngModel of the first dropdown. You define `value:any[]=[]` and use some like `[(ngModel)]="value[i]"` -else when you change a value of the formControl change the options of all the elements of the array-

Comment: tried it, but got an error how to change the [value]="item with the specific item" for example i want the assetConditionType only i tried to submit it but i got all the item of the assetCondtionType

Comment: @Alluring, I want to say that if you are interesting only in a "property" of the **second** dropdown, the first it's necesary the whole object because, in this code, you use the property "items" to feed the second dropdown. In this case you can use [value]="item.assetsConditionType", but all the values get the same.

Comment: i interested both of the dropdown @Eliseo

Comment: @Alluring, uptaded the answer

Comment: what if i want the value of "assetConditionType": "SERVICEABLE",
"tranType": "MAINTENANCE"? only sorry for more asking

Comment: Take a look the "[value]" of the options, if you use item.id get the "id", if you use item.assetConditionType and item.tranType you get the values you want: NOTE: Inn this case if you use the third option you need change the find by some like:`this.selectedOptions = this.options.find((x) => x.assetConditionType== value).items;`

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xvs5ud-hoynbz tried this one @Eliseo

Comment: When use the [(NgModel)] in the first dropdown, you use "item" as option. See that is the "change" who give value to the formControl:`(selectionChange)="form2.get('assetID')?.setValue(value.assetConditionType);..."`. In this case you needn't ngOnInit or the auxiliar variables.

Comment: i actually get your point. that the dropdown gives all the list in the second box but how should i display the assetConditionType instead of id. tried what you said but got me a error


form2:{
"assetID":SERVICEABLE
  "id": UPGRADE
}
like this one

Comment: I get it now!!!

Comment: what about if i used the trigger value? @Eliseo